# confused by html5, utf-8 and 8859-1

Tags: html, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Yesterday I upgraded an html page from "4.01 strict" to html5.
* http://r0k.us/rock/games/CoH/HallsOfHeroes/ 
The character encoding is iso-8859-1.  The http://validator.w3.org fails and won't even parse it when utf-8 is specified as charset, apparently because I use footnote characters such as ² .  They are in the upper 128 bytes of the character set.  What confuses me is that I keep reading that the first 256 bytes of utf-8 **is** 8859-1.

Does anyone know why the page won't validate as utf-8 ?

Comment: The first *128* characters of UTF-8 are ASCII. The upper 128 characters differ

Comment: And ASCII is really 7 bits, only having 128 characters encoded. Anything that is 8 bit is _extended_ ASCII and completely depends on the code page/encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character ² ("SUPERSCRIPT TWO") is represented by the number 0xb2 (178 decimal) -- but it's *represented* differently in 8859-1 and UTF-8.

In 8859-1, it's represented as a single byte with the value 0xb2.

In UTF-8, it's represented as two consecutive bytes with the values 0xc2, 0xb2.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) for an explanation of the encoding.

(8859-1 is more compact that UTF-8 for files containing 8-bit characters, but it's incapable of representing anything past 255. UTF-8 is compatible with ASCII and with 8859-1 for 7-bit characters, is reasonably compact for most text, and can represent more than a million distinct characters.)

A file containing only 7-bit characters can be interpreted either as ASCII, 8859-1, or UTF-8. A file containing 8-bit characters cannot; it has to be translated.

If you're on a Unix-like system with the `iconv` command installed, this:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8
```

will perform the appropriate translation.

Comment: Obviously I misunderstood the relationship between 8859-1 and utf-8.  Thanks for the corrections.  I had thought they were the same for all representable characters, with some code-page switch characters snuck into 128-159.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, only the first 128 code points are encoded in UTF-8 as ASCII, but UTF-8 is **not** ASCII, in particular, the next 128 code points differ.

You need to re-save the files as UTF-8 if you want them to be served as UTF-8.